# Hide <ion-nav-buttons> with ng-hide/ng-show

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

**I've tried conditionally hiding and showing elements in ion-nav-buttons element and found it to be laggy. There's time where both elements are visible making a jarring transition.**

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
   <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left" ng-hide="option.extra"></button>
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-android-arrow-back" ng-click="option.hideExtra()" ng-show="option.extra"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-android-color-palette" ng-show="option.extra"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Is there a way to fix this I haven't thought of? I've tried ng-if and ng-switch and the same thing happens.Please find [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/01OHVk6t3P3gOc3XY2iH?p=preview) for the same.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the problem? The Plunker is just a Plunker of the default template of ionic

Comment: Hi @JurClerkx would you please check it now ?

Comment: Hi @Abjo. I have just tried the using ng-if in the Plunker, and this solved the problem for me. Could you try this on a mobile device?

Comment: Hi @JurClerkx Thanks for trying but still the issue  remains. Have you just replace ng-show/ng-hide with ng-if ? or you wrote it some where else ?

Comment: Hi @JurClerkx I have resolved the issue using ng-class. ng-show/ng-hide is bit lagging thn ngclass. Thanks for your help. I have updated the plunker so you can check the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue using ng-class. ng-show/ng-hide is bit lagging thn ngclass. I have updated the plunker so you can check the same.

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left" ng-class="{hide:option.extra}"></button>
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-android-arrow-back" ng-class="{hide:!option.extra}" ng-click="option.hideExtra()"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">                
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-android-color-palette" ng-class="{hide:!option.extra}" ng-click="option.showColors()"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Please find the updated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/01OHVk6t3P3gOc3XY2iH?p=preview)

Comment: Excellent ! Is a really nice solution, great thank for sharing this trick ;)